# Ayuda con Diseño HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo mi programa de esa forma:

Y este es mi código:

```css
fieldset { 
border-radius: 5px;
border:5px solid #1F497D;
 background: #ddd;
 }

fieldset legend {
    background: #1F497D;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px ;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">  

<div id="demo-frame" title="click para arrastrar el elemento">
   <fieldset>
   

<legend>Lista 1</legend> 
 
   <ul id="lista1" >

   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li>Item3</li>
   <li>Item4</li>
   
   </ul>

   </fieldset>


   <div class="botonera1" title="click para mover todos los elementos"> 
   <fieldset>

   <legend>Move rows</legend> 

   <button onclick="moveriz()" id="button1">« Move All</button>
 <br>
   <button onclick="moverder()" id="button2">Move All »</button>

   </fieldset>
   </div>   
   <fieldset>

<legend>Lista 2</legend> 

   <ul id="lista2">
   <li>Item5</li>
   <li>Item6</li>
   <li>Item7</li>

   </ul>
   </fieldset>
</div>

 </div>
```

Y tan solo quiero acomodar mis tablas ¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: Probaste especificando divs con la clase `.col`?

Comment: Sip y aun me siguen fallando, aparte cuando pongo el .col se salen del panel-footer

Comment: Lo que pretendes es que se desplieguen de izquierda a derecha y alineadas verticalmente, no es así? O también quieres que resulte exactamente como en la imagen ?

Comment: De todos modos te recomiendo que te mires sobre las cajas flexibles de CSS => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hola @Javi, una pregunta, ¿tu usas el display: flex para centrar?

Comment: Te pregunto, porque lo use y mas o menos centro mis listas

Comment: Lo uso solamente cuando es necesario centrar elementos dentro de una caja flexible, pero no siempre se debe usar esta opción, depende de muchos factores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal así? [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5ChWQq74rCONjnxmhpx9?p=preview) . Sólo seccione un `div` con clase `row` en **subdivs** con `.col-xs-4` y quite los estilos que creaste. Podrías partir desde esta base :)

```css
/* Styles go here */

#button1,#button2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #1F497D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

   #lista1,#lista2{
 width:10px;
 height:auto;
 min-height: 50px;  
    text-alighn: center;
    }

    .botonera1{
 float:left;
 margin-right:28px;
    text-align: center;
    }

fieldset { 
border-radius: 5px;
border:5px solid #1F497D;
 background: #ddd;
 text-align: center;
 }

fieldset legend {
    background: #1F497D;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px ;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" title="click para arrastrar el elemento">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Lista 1</legend> 
             <ul id="lista1" >
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item2</li>
               <li>Item3</li>
               <li>Item4</li>
            </ul>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-4" title="click para mover todos los elementos"> 
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Move rows</legend> 
              <button onclick="moveriz()" id="button1">« Move All</button>
              <br>
              <button onclick="moverder()" id="button2">Move All »</button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-4" title="click para arrastrar el elemento">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Lista 2</legend> 
              <ul id="lista2">
               <li>Item5</li>
               <li>Item6</li>
               <li>Item7</li>
              </ul>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me funciono excelente!

Comment: el editor de respuestas de aquí también tiene la opción para agregar código ejecutable, es lo más recomendable

Comment: yo estaba usando el col-sm-4, pero se salia del panel-footer

Comment: Los `.cols` tienen distintas especificaciones - `xs, sm, md, lg` - dependiendo del dispositivo final (responsivo), debes ir jugando con eso para que se adapte correctamente a cada resolución. Colega **René** gracias por el dato, no lo sabía!

Comment: Solamente me falto preguntarle una cosa y espero que pueda ayudarme: ¿Como puedo centrar las listas?

Comment: Centrar las listas o centrar el texto dentro de las listas?

Comment: Centrar las listas, ponerlas en el centro de la pagina

Comment: El texto ya pude centrarlo, pero centrar las listas en la pagina no me ha salido, deje edito su programa para que vea que ya pude centrar el texto

Comment: Estoy utilizando display: flex para centrar